# Docker specific installation version. Dependency failed

Tags: docker

Needed a specific version of docker (18.06.1-ce). Removed newer version. Followed: http://www.devopsage.com/how-to-install-docker-on-ubuntu-16-04/ to install.

(ubuntu-16-04)

In the end, `systemctl status docker.service` got an exception like this:

> Dependency failed for Docker Application Container Engine.

Already spent some time googling. No luck.

Q: How it could be fixed?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK.
 Maybe it will save time for someone. The key was to remove previous version like with this command. (Seems something stuck unremoved that caused that issue). Removed again, followed the steps, all started being Ok. again.

To remove:

> sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker-ce docker.io

Before I did:

> sudo apt-get remove docker docker-ce. // not good